# PHP: Make a table showing cookies and allow user to select and remove cookies

Tags: php, html, cookies

I've been working on this for like a week. I'm in school right now and time is limited so it's really dragging me down (and also late, at this point) because I can't figure how the heck to get this to work fully.

The long and short of it is that I need to have a table showing (at least) 3 cookies. Their keys, values are:

color, green
menu, left
size, 10

They should be in a table with checkbox selection options on each cookie. The cookies can be selected, and then a "delete" button allows them to be deleted. Once deleted, the user now sees just a table of the cookies they DID NOT select on the page.

I keep getting close and then not able to get the dang table to actually delete the cookies. I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio Code with Xampp, which I have Apache running on.

Any help would really be appreciated. I'll put the code I have below. Thanks so much!

```
    <?php
    $c_cookies = [
            "color" => "green",
            "menu" => "left",
            "size" => 10
     ];
      foreach ($c_cookies as $key => $value) {
            setcookie($key,$value);
      }
    ?>

    <?php
      error_reporting(0);
      echo "<h3>List of Cookies : </h3>";
      echo "<table border='1' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='10'> <form action=' ' method='post'>";
      foreach ($_COOKIE  as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td> $value </td> <td><input type='checkbox' name='check' value='$key'></td><tr>";
    }
    echo " <tr><td colspan='3'><input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'></td></tr></form></table> ";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
            $x = $_POST['check'];
            if(empty($x))
            {
                    echo "<br><p2 style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>Please Select Cookie</p>";
            }
            else{   
            setcookie($x, "", time() - 3600);
            echo "<h2 style='color:red;'>Cookie Deleted</h2>";
            header("Refresh:0");
            }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Cookies will probably be deleted but they're re-set at the top of the page for every reload/refresh

Comment: Ugh how do i list them but also make them not refresh??? This assignment blows haha

Comment: Keep track of which cookies you deleted and don't re-set them again